# Не вызывается событие клика

Tags: c#, .net-6, winui3, windows-app-sdk

Переписываю тут проект на WinUI3 и столкнулся с некой особенностью, суть которой в том, что если я использую один контрол в другом, то у него перестает работать событие "клика".

##### Более подробно:

Активно используется CommunityToolkit с их элементами управления, а именно проблема замечена со следующей связкой:

- [SettingsExpander](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Windows/tree/main/components/SettingsControls/src)
- [MarkdownTextBlock](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Markdown/MarkdownTextBlock) (исходники именно WinUI не нашел, пакет `CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Markdown`)

Разметка получается такая:

```
<controls:SettingsExpander>
    <controls:SettingsExpander.Items>
        <communityControls:MarkdownTextBlock 
                           LinkClicked="MarkdownTextBlock_LinkClicked" 
                           Text="[ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)"/>
    </controls:SettingsExpander.Items>
</controls:SettingsExpander>
```

Событие смысла показывать нет, оно пустое, автоматически сгенерированное студией.

В итоге, данный код выводит как надо на экран кликабельную ссылку, нажимаю, а реакции нет, но если написать просто

```
<communityControls:MarkdownTextBlock 
                   LinkClicked="MarkdownTextBlock_LinkClicked" 
                   Text="[ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)"/>
```

То событие срабатывает без каких либо проблем.

Проблему удалось воспроизвести без `MarkdownTextBlock`, написав к примеру `<TextBlock Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" Text="1234567"/>`, а вот "аналог" `SettingsExpander` из стандартных, который воспроизведет проблему, найти (для упрощения вопроса) пока не смог.

Собственно, **вопрос**: Как решить данную головоломку? Тут явно надо как-то пробросить событие, но как, понятия не имею...

В теории аналогичное воспроизводится и на UWP (схожи по компонентам), и в теории на WPF (что-то подобное видел довольно давно, но не уверен наверняка).

Решения из интернета говорят "Ты возьми, по имени обратись, и укажи событие", только вот проблема во вложенности, даже если и будет такое решение, то я не могу просто так сделать `Имя.Событие += ...;`,  мне надо разбирать каждый `SettingsExpander`, докапываясь до его внутренностей, что звучит так себе...

**Дополнение**
Переписал разметку таким образом

```
<controls:SettingsExpander ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items}">
    <controls:SettingsExpander.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <communityControls:MarkdownTextBlock LinkClicked="MarkdownTextBlock_LinkClicked"  Text="[ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:SettingsExpander.ItemTemplate>
</controls:SettingsExpander>
```

То есть, задал коллекцию объектов через `ItemsSource` (простой массив чисел), и задал явный шаблон элемента, событие начало отрабатывать, событие вызывалось из View без каких либо проблем. Но это весьма странное решение, когда мне нужен лишь один конкретный элемент в раскрывающемся меню.

Попробовал воспроизвести это на стандартных контролах, например, так:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <Button Content="123" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

Проблему не воспроизводит, что наводит на мысль, что что-то не так в `SettingsExpander`...

Comment: Обработчики событий можно биндить через x:Bind, пробовали? Объекты внутри `ContentControl` могут укладываться в `DataTemplate`, в котором контект подчиняется значению `DataContext`. Вот и получается, что обработчик ваш за пределами контекста оказывается. То есть это плюс-минус похожее поведение на то как привязываются команды. Кстати, советую на x:Bind переходить. Боль ещё та, в плане того, что там Mode надо явно задавать, но оно того стоит. Другими словами, попробуйте контролу внутри экспандера прибиндить датаконтекст туда, где лежит обработчик, или обработчик переложить по аналогии команды.

Comment: Я сам тулкит не использую, поэтому могу только по нативке консультировать. Если не сможете разобраться, сделайте воспроизводимый пример, желательно безтулкитный.

Comment: @aepot привязать через `x:Bind` событие - пробовал, не работает, точней как, событие `Loaded` пробросило, а событие клика нет. "плюс-минус похожее поведение на то как привязываются команды." - Я думал об этом, сделал простой `ItemsControl` с шаблоном элемента, внутри которого `MarkdownTextBlock` из вопроса, вывел на экран 5 одинаковых ссылок, все работали, событие вызывалось, а вот внутри `SettingsExpander` не хочет... Также другой парадокс, я внутрь `SettingsExpander` размещал кнопку с событием клика, и она работала, когда как ссылка нет.

Comment: "Воспроизводящий пример" - все, что смог - в вопросе, из стандартных, увы, я не смог найти подобного поведения, пытался, только вот эта связка двух контролов так чудит. Если что, они из `CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Markdown` (`xmlns:communityControls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"`) и `CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls.SettingsControls` (`xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls"`)

Comment: Попробуйте SettingsExpander ItemsSource+ItemTemplate+DataTemplate и вынести обработчик в датаконтекст, ради эксперимента хотя-бы, WinAppSDK кстати вместо ItemsControl, используют ItemsRepeater. Ну и новомодный ItemsView есть, о нём можно почитать релизноутах 1.4  я уже с ним повоевал. И таких странностей и без тулкита полно. Крашится всё что можно со всякими unspecified error, catastrophic failure и прочими not all components were installed. Но слава богу, мне пока удалось побороть всё что я встречал, хотя горело у меня знатно.

Comment: Например если когда-то захотите прибиндить IsSelected в контроле коллекции, не важно какой, вас ждёт увлекательное приключение :) А ещё если будете использовать NavigationView с фреймом, то можете внезапно узнать, что x:Bind не всегда отписывается от PropertyChanged, и сеттеры начинают дергаться по 50 раз после длительной работы приложения, пришлось писать жесткий костыль, чтобы отписывать эту всю мусорную гадость от VM.

Comment: _исходники именно WinUI не нашел_ - Microsoft.UI.Xaml либа разрабатывается отдельно от WinAppSDK

Comment: @aepot Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Дополнение выглядит как решение, оформите ответом. Здесь что-либо лучше вряд-ли можно ответить.

Comment: @aepot Да ну, должно быть решение лучше. Неужели нет возможности пробросить событие? Да и почему только эти контролы так ерундой страдают? В голове что-то не укладывается это все. Создавать коллекции пустышки ради того, чтоб вывести одну строчку текста, ну бред ведь.

Comment: А почему вы используете Click? Там Command не поддерживается? Ну и можно же модель данных нормальную под коллекцию текстоссылок сделать. Зачем в XAML это всё хардкодить? Ну или заверните это в какой-нибудь юзерконтрол. x:Bind к кодбихайнду вяжется, так что можно будет запаковать этот баг полностью внутри юзерконтрола. Можно и не коллекцию, можно геттер или метод с `yield return`. x:Bind можно к методам вязать. Да, с DataTemplate x:DataType уже познакомились?

Comment: @aepot Команды не поддерживает, в Issue на гитхабе нашел [это](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/1772). Что касается "зачем хардкодить" - у меня простой объект, условно "Предмет", у которого есть название и описание, где описание должно поддерживать Markdown разметку, описание большое, и чтоб оно не занимало всю страницу, я хочу его скрыть в `Expander`, то есть, если не смотреть на Markdown, у меня там простой `<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Description}">`. И тут я без понятия, зачем у `SettingsExpander` контент сделали коллекцией...

Comment: В общем, ответ у меня есть, но он ничем не отличается от вашего дополнения. Вообще с хардкодом там беда, я в `RadioButton` в XAML поставил `IsChecked="True"` однажды, и у меня начало крашится при навигации на страницу, при чем не всегда, а один раз из трёх. То есть у либы UI.Xaml аллергия на хардкод, всё надо уносить в VM. При чём саму VM надо не в конструктор Page тащить как IoC завещал, а в метод OnNavigatedTo, а в методе OnNavigatedFrom об-null-ять (INPC не требуется, но можно DP). Тогда будет гарантирована более-менее стабильная работа, но я сам ещё не догрыз этот орех.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге, адекватного объяснения данной проблеме я так и не нашел, пришлось городить костыли, а именно:

Так, как `SettingsExpander` непонятно почему содержит в себе коллекцию объектов, я вынес `MarkdownTextBlock` в `ItemTemplate`,

```
<controls:SettingsExpander>
    <controls:SettingsExpander.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <communityControls:MarkdownTextBlock LinkClicked="MarkdownTextBlock_LinkClicked" Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:SettingsExpander.ItemTemplate>
</controls:SettingsExpander>
```

Ну а так, как у  меня один объект (простой текст), а не коллекция, надо как-то привязать, сделал это при помощи присоединяемого свойства (attached property)

```
public class SettingsExpanderExtensions : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SingleItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SingleItem", typeof(string), typeof(SettingsExpanderExtensions),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnPropertyChanged)
   );

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is SettingsExpander settingsExpander && e.NewValue is string)
        {
            settingsExpander.ItemsSource = new[] { e.NewValue };
        }
    }

    public static void SetSingleItem(SettingsExpander element, object value)
    {
        element.SetValue(SingleItemProperty, value);
    }
    public static object GetSingleItem(SettingsExpander element)
    {
        return element.GetValue(SingleItemProperty);
    }
}
```

Простое свойство, которое при обновлении значения, если оно на нужном нам `SettingsExpander`, задает ему `ItemsSource` как `new[] { e.NewValue }`, где `NewValue` простая строка...

Использование такое

```
<controls:SettingsExpander ui:SettingsExpanderExtensions.SingleItem="{Binding Description}">
```

В итоге, событие успешно отрабатывает, хоть и пришлось прибегнуть к костылям...
Если есть решение более правильное или более элегантней, буду рад его увидеть.

Comment: Только минорные оговорки: `e.NewValue is string` лишняя проверка, так как DP имеет уже тип `string`. `d is SettingsExpander` тоже, так как `d` никогда не будет null. То есть от бранча можно избавиться простым кастом. А лучше даже глянуть, от какого родителя у него `ItemsSource` и кастить к нему. `string.Empty` тоже можно заменить на `null`, ничего не должно отломаться. А так, вполне вменяемый костыль. Я ещё бы `Binding` на `x:Bind` заменил, но это дело вкуса. Предпочитаю, чтобы оно падало при компиляции, если что-то не так, а не молча неработало в рантайме. :)

Comment: `SetSingleItem`, `GetSingleItem` разве на свойство нельзя заменить? Чисто чтобы код локаничнее читался. Причём свойство типа `string`, а не `object`.

Comment: @aepot Проверки - как говорится, береженного бог бережет) `x:Bind` - Тут не совсем дело вкуса. Как я понял, это "генератор кода", он производительней обычного, но не всегда ведь нужна эта генерация, также у него есть ряд отличий, к примеру, он не привяжет в `DataTemplate` к существующему свойству, пока не укажешь явный тип и все, что необходимо для него, ну и про режим привязки не стоит забывать, по умолчанию у него стоит, как я  понял, "один раз взять и забыть", когда как у `Binding` по умолчанию стоит односторонняя связь (что у меня чаще всего и используется).

Comment: Что касается свойства - это ведь присоединяемое свойство, а они статичны, ну а статикой не обратиться к `GetValue` и `SetValue` без экземпляра контрола.

Comment: Про свойство ОК, что-то я не подумал, а про `x:Bind` `x:DataType="sys:String"` можно, и просто `{x:Bind Mode=OneWay}`, хотя xmlns для System придётся подключать. По поводу режима по умолчанию `Binding`, он через `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` задаётся. Например, если вы привяжете Text у TextBox, то будет по умолчанию TwoWay. А вот то что x:Bind полностью игнорит эти флаги, вот здесь и неудобство.

Comment: @aepot `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` нет в WinUI3, игрался сегодня с этим, так и не нашел как устанавливать режим привязки по умолчанию, видать из-за `x:Bind` много чего от стандартной привязки выпилили и в будущем будут все сильнее кастрировать, переводя всех на `x:Bind`.